# PHP : applying operation on exploded string in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, string

i have a  few products in my database that are being fetched in loop, now what i want is if i get a specific brand name in loop the  price value of that brand should be multiplied by 10 , brand names are stored in image  coloumn , like for brand a its a.png  so i need to get a and get its rate value multiplied by 10

i tried to explode string  and then take substring from starting to the dot means a.png , i got a but when i apply rate * 10 that does not work with that , need your help with this

Comment: Please give us a [mcve]  so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: show us the code you used, screenshots of the tables and illustrative examples of what you would like to do